# How do I create 1000 fast random graphs using Networkx?

Tags: python, random, graph, networkx

Create A graph using fast_gnp_random_graph, then for each graph calculate transitivity.  Number of graphs created should equal 1000.  Not understanding where the randomness comes in:

```
tran = []
n = 100 #Nodes
m = 500 #Expected Edges
p = m/(n*(n-1)/2)

GG=nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(n,p)
for i in range(1000):
    tran.append(nx.transitivity(GG))
```

Comment: Am I supposed to randomize the number of edges as a seed?

Comment: You simply need to create the graph within the for-loop.

Comment: `GG` was created once.  Consider flipping a coin and then leaving it on the table where it lands.  It might be heads.  It might be tails.  It's value is random, but each time you look it is the same value.  So I don't know what it is, but I know it's not going to change.  Here you've created a single random graph.  You then calculate its transitivity 1000 times.